# Why are these Google cookies being downloaded?

Tags: google, cookie

After removing cookies in Chrome, visiting my site, and requesting `chrome://settings/cookies`, I get this (my site is the last entry):

[image: 5 cookies: the first 4 Google-related, the last one from my website]

But since I have just removed Google Analytics script, I don't know why there is a cookie related to Google Analytics. Apart from that, I don't know why there are other cookies related to Google. I expected no cookies were downloaded when this page is visited …

FYI, I'm just trying to know if I need to add a cookies notice for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have removed the Google Analytics script (which is client-side JavaScript) then it's possible that your browser is loading a cached version of the page that does have the Google Analytics script, which then sets the cookies. However, GA sets `_ga` and `_gat` - which do not appear to be set.

What makes you think it is your site that is setting these (third party?) cookies? They are not for your domain.

However, your site is still reportedly using "Local Storage" - which is also part of the "EU Cookie Directive" (if that is what you are referring to).

Answer (score 1):

You still have plenty of references to google in your page source code.  Any one of them could be serving cookies.

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.**googlecode**.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css" />-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Mareva Productos Limpieza Profesional: Automoción Hostelería Industria" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mareva.es/bundles/placasfrontend/images/logo-mareva-fb.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://mareva.es/" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Mareva Productos de Limpieza Químicos es una empresa de distribución de productos químicos de limpieza profesionales para su uso multiples sectores: automoción, hostelería, industría, etc." />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1407482179520993" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/7b47665.css" />
<!--<a href="https://plus.`google`.com/116060764569911111964" rel="publisher">Google+</a>-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
 var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
 po.src = 'https://apis.**google**.com/js/platform.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>
```